# Cannot change list while iterating

Tags: python, list

Hey guys I am aiming to begin learning python by making a simple tool box that I can use while I am in vim.  Here is my attempt to make a binary to decimal calculator but I cannot seem to change my list while iterating.  I am a python beginner coming from C. Thanks. 
This what I am trying to do mentally:

100 -> [1, 0, 0] --> [1*2^2, 0*2^1, 0*2^0] --> 4+0+0 =4

```
 import sys

 #binary to decimal

 print("Needs to be ran in python3\n")
 print("Value:")

 digits=input()
 # add except statement here
 length=len(digits)-1
 digits = [int(x) for x in str(digits)]

print(digits)

for x in range(len(digits)):
      digits=x*(2**length)
      length=length-1

sum=sum(digits)
print(sum)
```

Comment: `digits=x=x*(2**length)`? Doesn't look correct to me, but then I don't know python. Anyhow, you should give an example of input for which it fails, and the output you got.

Comment: Why are you trying to change the list while iterating over it?

Comment: @user2357112 for this purpose: [1*2^2, 0*2^1, 0*2^0] so I can then sum the array

Comment: You don't have to modify the list while iterating over it to compute that sum.

Comment: If you are a beginner try to avoid list comprehensions. Start with simple functions. It will be easier to spot a mistake if you do every step separately.

Comment: @hnefatl edited to fix

Comment: @tom wojcik well it seems changing from arrays (C programming) to list is more difficult then I thought.

Comment: I think the line you want is `digits[x]=x*(2**length)`, but @user2357112 is right that you probably should do it without modifying the list. This is about the same as you would do in C.

Comment: @Daniel H I don't know any other way

Comment: @gethelplearning: Python variables are not pointers, no. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: You shouldn't clobber the `sum` function by creating a variable with the same `name`. The Python `int` constructor can accept a binary string, but I guess it's instructive to write your own code to do it. You really don't need a list for this, you can just iterate over the chars of the `digits` string. And there's no point doing `str(digits)`, since `digits` is already a string.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
digits=x*(2**length)
```

means “Set the variable `digits` to hold `x*(2**length)`”. Since `digits` was the only way you had to access the list of digits, and you have just made it hold a single digit, you lose access to the rest of the list (and Python realizes this and destroys the list). Instead, it looks like you want to set the `x`th element of `digits`, which can be accessed with `digits[x]`. This means the line you want would be

```
digits[x] = digits[x]*(2**length)
```

However, this isn’t the best way to accomplish this goal. For one thing, you are just adding a bunch of numbers together; it would be easier to do that without changing the list. For example:

```
total = 0

for x in range(len(digits)):
      total += digits[x] * (2**length)
      length=length-1

print(total)
```

(I changed the variable name from `sum` to `total` because it’s often a bad idea to override the built-in names)

Note that now the only way we access `x` is by calling `digits[x]`. It’s generally more idiomatic to iterate over the list itself, rather than the indices:

```
total = 0

for digit in digits:
      total += digit * (2**length)
      length=length-1

print(total)
```

This loop can be simplified to not need the `length` variable at all:

```
total = 0

for digit in digits:
      total *= 2
      total += digit

print(total)
```

This doubles `total` first, and then adds the next digit to it. This is both more readable (since `length` as a name usually indicates *total* length, which doesn’t change, so reducing it seems weird) and works even if we don’t know how many digits we have.

---

Another note is how you generate the `digits` list:

```
digits = [int(x) for x in str(digits)]
```

At this point, `digits` is already a `str` (because it’s the result of `input()`), so you don’t need to convert it with a call to `str`; just say `[int(x) for x in digits]`

---

Finally, there’s an easier method for all of this. If we run the command `help(int)` in the Python interpreter, we see that the `int` constructor is documented as follows:

> `int(x=0) -> integer`
>    `int(x, base=10) -> integer`
>
> Convert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments
>    are given.  If `x` is a number, return `x.__int__()`.  For floating point
>    numbers, this truncates towards zero.
>
> If `x` is not a number or if base is given, then `x` must be a string,
>    bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in the
>    given base.  The literal can be preceded by `'+'` or `'-'` and be surrounded
>    by whitespace.  The base defaults to 10.  Valid bases are 0 and 2-36.
>    Base 0 means to interpret the base from the string as an integer literal.
>
> ```
> >>> int('0b100', base=0)
> 4
> ```

This means that you can just make your entire program

```
# There's no need to import sys; you never use it

#binary to decimal

# Your original program do the same thing in Python 2 and 3
print("Value:")

digits=input()
print(int(digits, 2))
```

Of course, that version doesn’t do as good a job at your stated goal of beginning to learn Python.

Comment: How could I possibly _not_ upvote this? ;) Well done!

Comment: @PM2Ring The only thing you mentioned in your OP comment which I didn’t include was iterating over the string directly. I thought of it, but then you’d still need to call `int` in the for loop each time, and I can see preferring that to be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

By any chance, did you mean to write

```
digits[x] = x*(2**length)
```

in your for loop? Since `digits` in a list, you're basically setting the entire `digits` list to a single value in that for loop. Try that and see if that works.